# How to show/hide a div in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, button

When i click the button i want the div to show, and when i click the button again i want it to disappear. What am i doing wrong?

```js
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>

<div id="Dglow" class="Dglow">
    Glow
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var e = document.getElementById("Dglow").style.display;
    if (e == "none")
        e = "block";
    else {
        e = "none";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should compare and change element's `display` property:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var e = document.getElementById("Dglow").style;
    if (e.display == "none") {
        e.display = "block";
    } else {
        e.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>

<div id="Dglow" class="Dglow">Glow</div>
```

Comment: Shorthand  `e.display =   e.display == "block" ? "none" : "block";`

Answer (score 1):

Actually `document.getElementById("Dglow").style.display` returns a string and according to Left hand assignment rule you cannot store anything to that string, since that string is not a variable/object now ie not a reference to DOM anymore

You can do is

```
var e = document.getElementById("Dglow").style;
if(e.display == "none")
   e.display = "block";
else{
   e.display = "none";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using Jquery? If so heres what you need.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
        $("#Dglow").toggle();
    });
});
```

You would need to give your button an id for this though.